# I tried to replace my old and outdated master branch with my current dev branch, but it didn't work

Tags: git

I have a local branch that I want to be the new master both locally and remote.  My master is so out of date and way behind my dev branch so this is the best choice.

So I looked on here at a lot of similar questions, and tried the below.

```
git branch -f master myDev_That_I_Want_To_Be_MASTER
git push origin +myDev_That_I_Want_To_Be_MASTER:master
git add *
git commit -m "Push to remote GIT"
git push origin HEAD
```

I didn't get any errors, but when I do a `git status`, it still shows that I'm on my dev branch and not master:

```
On branch myDev_That_I_Want_To_Be_MASTER
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

How can I make sure that it worked?

Thanks!

Comment: "but when I do a git status, it still shows that I'm on my dev branch and not master" Because that's where you were when you started, and you never asked to be elsewhere. And you didn't delete the develop branch. So there you are, still. — But now `git checkout master` and then use `git status` and especially `git log` to see what the situation is. How does that look?

Comment: @matt oh ok, thanks, that makes sense.  I did the `git checkout master` and `git status` says, `Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.`  But `git log` shows the most recent thing to be done was back in June. Also, I don't see any of the many changes/additions made to the dev branch that I tried to make master.

Comment: Well, `git branch -f master myDev_That_I_Want_To_Be_MASTER` does the main thing you say you want to do. Everything else you said is pretty much unnecessary (though of course sooner or later one must push-with-force). So I don't understand why `git log` doesn't show what you expect.

Comment: @matt maybe I'm mistaken in thinking that my `master` branch will still be named `master`?  Or did it assume the name of the branch that I made master?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are we talking about the _local_ situation or the _remote_ situation (up at GitHub or whatever)?

Comment: @matt its good now, your answer both explained and fixed it all!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only really important line in what you did was the first line. I'll demonstrate:

```
$ git log
commit 6f7f7f37ab50cb9c965599ef747136987be0daf7 (HEAD -> master)
    make c
commit 926972673ab7e7dbf779d22a88e32c4373da68ad
    make b
commit f9e7c583802682979ae0f2b33afebd686106f984
    make a
$ ls
a.txt   b.txt   c.txt
```

Okay, so we have three commits on master and three files in the work tree (and they are all committed into the commits).

Now I'm going to make a branch right at the start and make a commit on it:

```
$ git branch branch -- f9e7c583
$ git checkout branch
Switched to branch 'branch'
$ echo 'hellooo' > z.txt
$ git add .
$ git commit -m'make z'
```

Now I'm going to do what you did! I'm going to *force* the name `master` to jump to where the name `branch` is:

```
$ git branch -f master branch
```

So let's take stock:

```
$ git log master
commit 34292442b2e37079d480fe73ea53ccfaa82b7707 (HEAD -> branch, master)
    make z
commit f9e7c583802682979ae0f2b33afebd686106f984
    make a
$ ls
a.txt   z.txt
```

Yup, well, as you can see, the entire history of `master` is now exactly the history of `branch`, because at this moment they are the same commit. The files that existed only in `master` are gone. The commits that existed only in `master` are gone. We have turned `master` into `branch`.

So what I'm suggesting is that the way to ascertain "success" is to look at `git log myDev_That_I_Want_To_Be_MASTER` and at `git log master` and you should see that they have identical *histories*. That is what was desired.